# How to map numbers to list elements in python

Tags: python

I have this variable `attributes` that contains lists:

```
print(attributes)

    ['glucose_tol', 'age']
    ['glucose_tol', 'age', 'mass_index']
    ['glucose_tol', 'age', 'mass_index']
    ['age']
    ['age']
    ['glucose_tol', 'age']
    ['glucose_tol', 'age']
    []
    ['glucose_tol', 'age']
    ['glucose_tol', 'age', 'mass_index']
```

What I want is to map `glucose_tol to 17.61`, `mass_index to 1.00` and `age to 1.00` and then add these up.
So for example `[17.61, 1.00]` will be `18.61`, for `['17.61', '1', '1']` will be `19.61` etc and then add all these up to a number.

I looked at python's `map()` function but I don't know how to use it in this case, because I have many lists in one variable.

when I do:

```
  print(type(attributes))
  print(attributes)
```

I get :

```
<class 'list'>
['glucose_tol', 'age']
<class 'list'>
['glucose_tol', 'age', 'mass_index']
<class 'list'>
['glucose_tol', 'age', 'mass_index']
and so on...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```py
total = 0
mapping = {
    ”glucose_tol”: 17.61,
    ”age”: 1.0,
    ”mass_index”: 1.0
}
for attr in attributes:
    for item in attr:
        total += mapping[item]
```

Answer (score 2):

please test this:

```
mapping = {'glucose_tol': 17.61, 'age': 1, 'mass_index': 1}

values = [
    ['glucose_tol', 'age'],
    ['glucose_tol', 'age', 'mass_index'],
    ['glucose_tol', 'age', 'mass_index']
]

for i in values:
    print(sum([mapping[y] for y in i]))
    # with map
    print(sum(list(map(lambda x: mapping[x], i))))
```

Comment: or `sum(map(mapping.get, i))`

Comment: thank you, this works. But I have one problem, you've put the lists inside a list, and I have it differently. When I do print(attributes) I do not get `[ ['glucose_tol', 'age'], ['glucose_tol', 'age', 'mass_index'] ]` but instead `['glucose_tol', 'age'] ['glucose_tol', 'age', 'mass_index'] ...` a series of many lists. That's how I generate them with another function.

Comment: But what type is attributes? A string?

Comment: @MrNobody33 they are lists actually. I will add it in my initial question to be more clear.

Comment: Yeah I just saw your edit, but there says that attributes is a list, colud you test what outputs when ´attibutes[0]´